# Are there any decent GWT Timeline libraries out there?

Tags: web-applications, gwt, timeline

### Example

I basically need something close to **the following image**:
[image: Timeline example]

### Existing Libraries

I already tried [**GWT Planning**](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-planning/), but I couldn't get it working. Right now I'm looking into [**GWT Simile Timeline**](http://code.google.com/p/gwtsimiletimeline/).

### Implementation

If there aren't any other usable timeline libraries, do you have any ideas **how I might implement one myself?**

Is using **a table** a good idea?

Won't there be some **performance issues**? (due to the fact that GWT already uses a lot of tables for the layouts and it takes some time until the browser renders the page).

---

### EDIT

### Final decision

I reviewed GWT Simile Timeline, but it doesn't do what I want and besides that the documentation is not finished and it seems to me that the project is discontinued.
I'll follow [Daniel Kurka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6021646/are-there-any-decent-gwt-timeline-libraries-out-there/6022024#6022024)'s suggestion (using cellTable).

### Open to suggestions

If there are any other suggestions I'm open to them...

---

### ANOTHER EDIT

Is it better if I use **FlexTable** for this type of things? I saw that it allows me to use any type of widget (but I think it has performance issues). I want to have up to 100-150 widgets on the timeline. Will performance be affected by this number of widgets?

Comment: There is also [gwt-chronoscope](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-chronoscope/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implementing a timeline with the Grid Widget would bring a lot of performance issues ( since a grid consists of widgets, which bring some overhead)

You might want to take a look into cellTable to see how bulkrendering is done.

Basically it renders the html as a string an sets it with SetInnerHTML. Event Handling is only done once on the root element. If you want to your own timeline this is a good starting point.